# Logout in MVC using Session without JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm relatively new to MVC 3 and I'm working with logging out my application, I managed to do the logging in, staying logged in even if website is opened on another tab.

All of my views (except for the home, of course) has this:

> `<a href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Logout</a>`

and in my controller I have this:

> `public ViewResult Logout()
>           {
>               Session.Abandon();
>               return View("Index", "Home");
>           }`

and the app is not logging out, instead it is returning the current view.

Please help me understand what to do, and I would like to take note that I am using ViewResult instead of ActionResult, I'm not also going to use JavaScript or JQuery, because I'm making this app to show how MVC works.

Comment: What is your "logon" mechanism? Why are you using `Session.Abandon()` to log user out?

Comment: Abandon() kills the session made after a valid login, I used SqlConnection.

Comment: `SqlConnection` is not a login mechanism, it's a data layer.

Comment: What do you mean with login mechanism, are you asking if I used something like FormAuthenticate?

Comment: What you mean by "login" then? There's no login if there's no authentication. What purpose does you "logout" have?

Comment: just checking if ModelState.IsValid then performs scanning in database if the inputs exist.

Comment: Why don't you use any of the built-in mechanisms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be pointing to the logout action?

```
<a href = "@Url.Action("Logout", "Home")">Logout</a>
```

Assuming the path to you're logout action is `\Home\Logout`

**UPDATE:**

Another old fashioned way is..

Upon successful login..

```
Session["Login"] = true; //or any object that describes the user's identity
```

On every page you need to check

```
var login = Session["Login"];
if(Convert.ToBoolean(login)){ //or cast to your expected object
  //do something
}
else{
  //redirect to logout/login page
}
```

Upon logout,

```
Session["Login"] = null;
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I also added this : Response.Redirect("~/"); after Session.Abandon();

Comment: Logout successful until I tried logging in again with same inputs and even tried with a different valid input, login became impaired. Then I saw that the URL has Home/Logout that's why I needed to use Response.Redirect

Answer (score 2):

If you are using forms authentication you should also clear the authentication cookie and redirect after logging out:

```
public ActionResult Logout() 
{ 
    Session.Abandon(); 
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
}
```